# Why does my Vscode IDE has Weird Error Messages when I run a C++ program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

[image: Weird error message]

I have vscode setup to run a c++ program.  Compiler is clang++.  I am not sure why all the red underline for "msg" and ":" showed up.  The program ran fine however.  What is wrong?

Comment: Object initialization is complex, there are a lot of rules to it. See [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) for some details.

Comment: Is your vscode configured to use C++11 or later?

Comment: set C++11 in your `cpp_settings.json`, your compiler might compile C++11,14,17 by default not the Language Server (Intellisence and diagnostic messages)

Comment: how you fix that you?